# NSData 2 Video URL?

Tags: nsdata, nsurl

need to convert a video file to NSData and then back to playable URL.  The NSData portion is as follows:

```
let videoNSD = NSData(contentsOfURL: videoPreview!)
// videoNSD is uploaded to cloud and then retrieved.. 

func playNSDataVideoPreview(videoNSD: NSData)
{
    // how to play in AVPlayer?
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]

    let filePath = documentsDirectory + "/" + "nsdfile-1234.mp4"
    let nsdURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

    videoNSD.writeToURL(nsdURL, atomically: true)

    mediaPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: nsdURL)
    playerController.player = mediaPlayer

    mediaPlayer.play()
}
```

What is the best practice for playing in AVPlayer?

Thanks...

Comment: what if video is too big ? like more than RAM ?

Comment: this is for small snippet vids.  i'll add code to limit .. thanks for the heads up..

Comment: would be better to download as a file and then open in player from file

Comment: agreed.. how can I convert the NSData file into useable format for AVPlayer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest to Upload/Download as file ( from File handle ) and not Data ( NSData ) , because videos might be bigger than RAM ( imagine a movie ).

To download File with Alamofire , you can use sample code from https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#downloading

```
Alamofire.download(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/stream/100") { temporaryURL, response in
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let directoryURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename

    return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)
}
```

after downloading and having a file, you can directly use `AVPlayer(URL URL: NSURL)`

If you have just NSData of video and want to play it, first save it as file and then create `AVPlayer` with your saved URL ( file location )

```
YOURVIDEODATA.writeToURL(URL_WHERE_TO_SAVE,atomically: true)
```

and then again use `AVPlayer(URL: URL_WHERE_TO_SAVE)`